# main.c:(.text+0x170): undefined reference to `sqrt' (used -lm)

Tags: c, makefile

ok, so i'm trying to compile my code using makefile, i've got only 2 .c file and 1 .h file, i used "sqrt()" function from math.h (only in main), here is my makefile:

```
a.out:  GBST.o main.o
        gcc GBST.o  main.o

GBST.o: GBST.c GBST.h
        gcc -c GBST.c

main.o: main.c
        gcc -c main.c -lm
```

still, I get main.c:(.text+0x170): undefined reference to `sqrt' error, what can it be? (btw, i wrote -lm in GBST line before and it did not help, so i have deleted it)

Comment: And where is the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows what you do?

Comment: Have you included math.h?

Comment: thank you you user3121023, it actually worked!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use `-lm` in the link line, not in the compile line.

```
a.out:  GBST.o main.o
        gcc GBST.o  main.o -lm
#                          ^^^^ Need it here

GBST.o: GBST.c GBST.h
        gcc -c GBST.c

main.o: main.c
        gcc -c main.c
#                     ^^^^ Don't need it here
```